# Register new customer and set id group

Tags: customer, register

I need to register the customer into group B2B (id group 2)

Now... in `register.phtml` file I insert

```
<input type="hidden" name="group_id" id="group_id" value="2" />
```

but it does not work.

In the backend the customer does not have a group

why?

Comment: Can u please share location of `register.phtml`?

Comment: /app/design/frontend/acquedilusso/acquedilusso-child/template/opc/customer/form

the file is correct but the group not work

Comment: You need to register the attribute `group_id` in the table `customer_form_attribute` with `form_code = customer_account_create`. You can get the `attribute_id` of `group_id` in the table `eav_attribute`

Comment: Please accept any of the answer, if it helped out to resolve your issue.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are using a customer `register.phtml` file which holds a customer registration form. Now you already included your group_id as a hidden field like this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="group_id" id="group_id" value="2" />
```

Now it is very important to do following things in your controller action method that deals with this form POST.

```
public function createPost()
{
    //initialize customer model
    $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer');
    $post     = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
    //set customer group id if it exists in post.
    if (isset($post['group_id'])) {
        $customer->setData('group_id', $post['group_id'])
    }
    //this will set default customer group id, if group_id is not set to customer
    $customer->getGroupId();

    ....
    $customer->save();
}
```

As you can see above, before doing your `$customer->save()`, you should set customer group id in `$customer` model.

The best place to look into in this situation is [`Mage_Customer_AccountController::createPost()`](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Customer/controllers/AccountController.php#L273) method. Specifically you need to go through following two calls in that method.

- [`Mage_Customer_AccountController::_getCustomer()`](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Customer/controllers/AccountController.php#L362) : This call will initialize customer model.
- [`Mage_Customer_AccountController::_getCustomerErrors()`](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Customer/controllers/AccountController.php#L414) : This basically deal with checking for any post data errors. If there is not, then setting up post data into customer model.

Hope you get the idea.

<sup>**Tip:** You should really avoid inserting customer group id as hidden field in your form. Since you already know the customer group that you want to set to customer, it is better to deal this in your controller method itself.</sup>

Comment: i solved the problem.
it need to insert # into a class. thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

Try running this statement in your database

```
INSERT INTO customer_form_attribute (form_code, attribute_id)
  SELECT 'customer_account_create', attribute_id 
  FROM eav_attribute WHERE attribute_code = 'group_id'
```